# How to install Ubuntu on a system where is already Mint and Windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, dual-boot, window

I have already installed Linux Mint on Windows 7 so now I have dual boot with Linux Mint and Windows 7.

They are both on diferent partitions.

I have 1 free partition left.

The question is how to install Ubuntu?

Should I just run it from CD and install it on the free partition?

Would I be able to run then all 3 systems (Ubuntu, Mint, Windows) from the menu when starting a computer or not?

How to do that?

Comment: Just follow the prompts. Ubuntu will ask you where to install, choose the right partition and you're done.

Comment: @terdon would I then be able to run all three systems from the GRUB menu when starting the computer? I thought that dual boot means that only 2 (2 = dual) systems can be run at the same time.

Comment: No dual boot is a misnomer, it actually means multiple. You can have as many OS's on a system as you have room on your HDD(s). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_boot

Comment: @slm OK, thanks. Can you put it as an answer, so I can tick your answer?

Comment: Yup, what @slm said :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dual boot is a misnomer, it actually means multiple. You can have as many OS's on a system as you have room on your HDD(s).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi_boot

In general when setting up dual boot systems you'll need to use one of the distros boot loaders such as Grub (linux) or [NTLDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR) (Windows) to manage the various OS installations that you've laid down on the HDD(s).